# Where are the cookbooks stored in Chef Server?

Tags: chef-infra

Environment:
CentOS 6
Chef 10
1 server, 1 node, 1 workstation

What is the location or path of the cookbooks uploaded to the Chef server?
For example, from the workstation,

## knife cookbook upload getting-started

Where does the cookbook go in the server?

Comment: I don't know about CentOS, but on Ubuntu it's `/var/lib/chef/cookbook_index`

Comment: I use Chef: 12.2.1 and ubuntu12, not sure where is cookbook in chef server

Comment: @JoelHandwell: On Chef server version 12.15.8, it's in `/var/opt/opscode/bookshelf/data/bookshelf/`

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the bookshelf, which is a configurable path. You can see the values on all platforms by looking at the [attributes file](https://github.com/cookbooks/chef-server/blob/qa/attributes/default.rb#L23) for the chef-server cookbook.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored in bookshelf directory , which can be modified and the files regarding the cookbook are located at /var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data/bookshelf . In that directory u can find all the cookbooks uploaded and also you can view the recipes .

Answer (score 0):

IN AWS linux, the cookbook files are located in **/var/opt/chef-server/bookshelf/data/bookshelf**

[check this link for more info](https://github.com/opscode/omnibus-chef-server/blob/master/files/chef-server-cookbooks/chef-server/attributes/default.rb)